# Queueing Runnable objects for execution in one thread

Tags: java

Is this possible to queue multiple Runnable objects to wait for execution in one thread? How it can be done without using ExecutorService? What's gonna happen if one of those Runnable objects threw unchecked exception, does it stop executing thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to queue multiple Runnable objects to wait for execution in one thread?

Use an ExecutorService.

> How it can be done without using ExecutorService?

Use a BlockingQUeue and Thread.

> What's gonna happen if one of those Runnable objects threw unchecked exception, does it stop executing thread?

That's up to you since you have to writ this yourself.

For an ExecutorService, the Throwable thrown is added to the Future object for you to check.  Its very easy to forget to do this, in which case you need to add a try/catch block to you Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason for not using an ExecutorService? It provides an implementation working in one Thread: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Comment: Yes specific reason here is how does underlying implementation of Executors work ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
Open a thread the listens to a queue, each time it sees a item, it deques and runs it.
You can wrap the execution of the task in a try catch block, thus allowing the worker thread to continue working even if one of the tasks threw an exception.

Having said that- the above is exactly what a ThreadPoolExecuter does, so why wouldn't you want to use it? (Homework?)

Comment: Ah not homework just because I would like to understand how ExecutorService work

Comment: @MinhHoang You can lookup the source code of `ExecutorService` in the file `src.zip` which is in your JDK installation directory.